# Mapping tomcat apache worker

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk, tomcat5.5

I am running an Apache2 server connected with Tomcat5.5

Workers.properties

```
workers.tomcat_home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
ps=/
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=127.0.0.1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

The JkMount is defined as follows

```
LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkMount /jsp-examples worker1
JkMount /jsp-examples/* worker1
JkMount /servlets-examples worker1
JkMount /servlets-examples/* worker1
JkMount /tcontainer worker1
JkMount /tcontainer/* worker1
```

If i call 127.0.0.1/servlets-examples, i get the examples displayed and executed correctly.

If i call [same server as above]/tcontainer, i get the following error:

```
The requested resource (/tcontainer) is not available. (this is an error provided by tomcat5.5)
```

How can i define where to get the sources?

i have a configuration file in /usr/share/tomcat-5.5-webapps/tcontainer.xml:

```
<Context path="/tcontainer" docBase="/var/www/web96/html/tcontainer"
   debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true">
</Context>
```

What did i forget to configure or what is wrong with my definitions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`docBase` is the pathname to the web application archive file . So, change:

```
<Context path="/tcontainer" docBase="/var/www/web96/html/tcontainer"
   debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true">
</Context>
```

to:

```
<Context path="/tcontainer" docBase="tcontainer"
   debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true">
</Context>
```

and try again.